# using grepl * to return NA values in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a dataset that has NA values. I'm filtering by using grepl by passing it search strings, and have been hoping to use "*" to return all values.

```
df <- structure(list(`Subject description` = c("Art & Design", "Chinese", 
"Classical Greek", "D&T Product Design", "Drama & Theatre Studies"
), `Discount code` = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

search <- "*"

df %>% filter(grepl(search, `Discount code`))
```

the above return an empty data frame. Is there a way for grepl to return NA values. I appreciate that I could `OR` the filter with `is.na(Discount code)`, but my code is using the search string and doesn't want to return na values if another value is provided to `string`

Comment: So you want your filter to return value if the content is NA or if it match your search pattern ?

Comment: I want both functionality, I was hoping "*" would return every row including NA, and that otehr regex values would onlt return what was being searched for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom function to do this:

```
greplna <- function(data, reg="*", var="Discount code"){
  if(reg == "*"){
    tmp <- grepl("*", as.list(data[var])[[1]]) | is.na(as.list(data[var])[[1]])
  }else{
    tmp <- grepl(reg, as.list(data[var])[[1]])
  }
  return(tmp)
}
```

You can then use this in a dplyr statement:

```
df %>% filter(greplna(., search, "Discount code"))
```

but don't use it after a group, as the `.` gets the whole dataset, not the grouped datasets

Comment: That is also a good option. You could using `{{ }}` and `ifelse` to simply the function: `function(x = "Discount code", reg="*"){ ifelse(reg == "*", (grepl("*", {{ x }}) | is.na({{ x }})), grepl(reg, {{ x }}))}`

Comment: I've not met `{{}}` before. what does it do differently?

Comment: It makes the function work with column names (symbols) and we don‘t need the data argument in this case. It’s explained in the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html) under "indirection".

Answer (score 1):

Would it be ok for you to replace `NA`s with `""`. Then you could use the search string to return all rows by looking for `"*"`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  replace_na(list("Discount code" = "")) %>%  
    filter(grepl("*", `Discount code`))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   `Subject description`   `Discount code`
#>   <chr>                   <chr>          
#> 1 Art & Design            ""             
#> 2 Chinese                 ""             
#> 3 Classical Greek         ""             
#> 4 D&T Product Design      ""             
#> 5 Drama & Theatre Studies ""
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since grepl return only TRUE or FALSE you can combine is.na and your grepl statement :

```
search <- "b"

df %>% filter(is.na(`Discount code`) | grepl(search, `Discount code`))
```

Comment: But wouldn't this return `NA`s no matter what the search string is? Is think if the search pattern is `"b"` then `NA` rows should not be selected.

Comment: Yes it does but from I understood he had an empty result which was expected from only using grepl therefore I thought he wanted to return the value matched by grepl but also the one equal to NA